# Custom SharePoint Timer Job doesn't run after changing code and restart timer services

Tags: development, jobs

I have an issue, Custom SharePoint timer do not take the new code. That package is fine in my server but not working in customer's server. I can't remote to his server to detect this, but he really reset the timer services.

Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you created the instance of your custom timer job after activate the feature you defined in  the web application, please try to reactivate it after you restart the SPTimer services.